# Как передать в функцию структуру?

Tags: c, функции, структуры, типы-данных

я объявил в main.c структуру

```
typedef struct student {
    char *name;
    char number_of_group[8];
    double score;
};
```

хочу передать в процедуру эту структуру

```
void console_output(struct student *mephist , int count_of_elements){
    int i = 0;
    while (i < count_of_elements) {
        printf("%s\n", mephist[i].name);
        printf("%s\n", mephist[i].number_of_group);
        printf("%f\n", mephist[i].score);
        i++;
    }
}
```

выдает ошибку
Subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'struct student'
подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Покаажите, что вы пытаетесь передать в функцию

Comment: в каком плане? у меня ошибку кидает на struct student в процедуре

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или просто пишите

```
struct student {
    char *name;
    char number_of_group[8];
    double score;
};
```

без `typedef` и передавайте как передаете, или дайте имя, например,

```
typedef struct student {
    char *name;
    char number_of_group[8];
    double score;
} Student_type;
```

и тогда передавайте

```
void console_output(Student_type *mephist , int count_of_elements){
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: тогда вылезает ошибка Unknown type name 'Student_type' . она и раньше была, когда я без typedef писал

Comment: все, разобрался. нашел такую статью на оригинальном over flow